# When to use "And" at the start of sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-starts, style-manuals, coordinating-conjunctions, is-it-a-rule

I know that *and* is used to join two sentences or phrases. There are some places I've read that have
*And* is used at the **beginning** of a sentence. What are the occasions when this is done?

Comment: Why is the question downvoted? Did I break any rule?

Comment: Downvotes are generally given because a question is judged as not useful or is lacking in research. In my view, an additional problem is that you’ve framed the question too broadly. Please read our guidance on [ask]. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start a sentence with a conjunction when you want to call a clause out for special emphasis. Examples:

> We finally won a game against Notre Dame. And our best player wasn't even in the game!
>   You can come up with $500 to pay the fine. Or you can spend 30 days in jail.
>   We were spent, bruised, broke, and bewildered. But at least we were home.

As you can see, each of those three examples could easily be rendered as single sentences. But breaking them up into a complete sentence and a sentence fragment beginning with a conjunction calls attention to the latter half. It elevates a second clause into an emphatic statement, which is somewhat more noticeable and memorable because of that.